# MySQL load Data with "true" in it

Tags: java, mysql, database, server

is it possible to load only the strings from my database to my server, which have "true" in it? E.g.: It should load"a.b.e.true" but not "a.b.e" When yes, how can I do that? I am using Java.

Comment: What kind of data? Explain yourself better, that was a really poor attempt.

Comment: I have like 30 rows, but I want only load the strings with "true" in it

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%true%';`

Answer (score 0):

Yes; it would be slow, but your query would be something like this:

```
SELECT string_column FROM table_name WHERE string_column LIKE '%true%'
```

If you also want to match on "TRUE", then you'd replace `LIKE` with `ILIKE` (which is case-insensitive).

Below is some example code for getting this data [[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)]

```
// Assuming you already have a Connection object named con
Statement stmt = null;
List<String> toRet = new ArrayList<String>();
String query = "SELECT string_column FROM table_name WHERE string_column LIKE '%true%'";

try
{
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        toRet.add(rs.getString("string_column"));
    }
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if(stmt != null)
    {
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```